# Display submenus in regular textflow

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

In the past days I switched my menu to mobile friendly version. Is nearly done so far, only one issue remains: In the desktop version I've positioned the submenus absolutely so that they cover what is below when made visible. However, in the mobile version I would like to have them in regular textflow, so that what is below slides down when I make them visible. I'm using mediaqueries and have tried to set the position attribute to "static" but this didn't work:
    #Navigation li ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
My test page: http://ulrichbangert.de/indexr3.php (Resize the viewport to a small width until the menu has one column.) I've used this tutorial: http://www.menucool.com/ddmenu/create-mobile-friendly-responsive-menu.aspx where it works just as I want it to. However I cannot use this one-by-one as I wanted to keep the layout of my existing menu. Best regards - Ulrich

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I was able to solve this problem on my own: Apparently some CSS attributes cannot be changed when they are in a nested list and not on top level. In this case the attribute position. Afterwards I had the same problem with the attribute width which I could not change to 100% and the attribute padding-left which I could not change either. And some years ago when I implemented the initial version of this menu with the attribute height, which I could not change to auto on hover after setting it to 0 initially. Only setting to a fixed height worked.
How can this be? Is it intended or is it a bug in the browsers implementation? (I tested with firefox).
Anyway my menu works fine now, just as I figured it.